# Python3 - convert csv to json using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, data-conversion

I've got a `.csv` files with 5 columns but I only need the `json` file to contain 3 of these how would i go about doing it?

csv file:

```
Ncode   Ocode   name    a     b     c 
  1      1.1     1x     1a    1b    1c
  2      2.2     2x     2a    2b    2c
  3      3.3     3x     3a    3b    3c
```

Json output:

```
{"1.1":[{"a":"1a"},{"b":"1b"},{"c":"1c"}],"2.2":[{"a":"2a"},{"b":"2b"},{"c":"2c"}]}
```

Comment: `{"1.1":{"a":"1a","b":"1b","c":"1c"},"2.2":{"a":"2a","b":"2b","c":"2c"}}` want this?

Comment: @MYGz, yes please, but there needs to be a [ ] enclosing the entries for the Ocode... so what you suggested is this; `{"1.1":{"a":"1a","b":"1b","c":"1c"},"2.2":{"a":"2a","b":"2b"‌​,"c":"2c"}}`, what i need is `{"1.1":[{"a":"1a","b":"1b","c":"1c"}],"2.2":[{"a":"2a","b":"2b"‌​,"c":"2c"}]}` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
txt = """Ncode   Ocode   name    a     b     c 
  1      1.1     1x     1a    1b    1c
  2      2.2     2x     2a    2b    2c
  3      3.3     3x     3a    3b    3c
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)


json.dumps(
    {'{:0.2f}'.format(r.Ocode): [{'a': r.a}, {'b': r.b}, {'c': r.c}]
     for r in df.itertuples()}
)

'{"2.20": [{"a": "2a"}, {"b": "2b"}, {"c": "2c"}], "3.30": [{"a": "3a"}, {"b": "3b"}, {"c": "3c"}], "1.10": [{"a": "1a"}, {"b": "1b"}, {"c": "1c"}]}'
```