# How turn nested iterrows with if statements into vectorized function or other faster method in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know that pandas.DataFrame.iterrows is really slow, for simple functions in pandas/python like "multiply each column by another column," vectorization is easy.

I have a problem that's a bit more complicated and I cannot figure out a way to vectorize or map the problem. I'm checking df1, the working dataframe, against the main dataframe to see if any entries are new. There are some quirks to the problem, each name can have multiple accounts and each account can have multiple possible names.

Without these small quirks, it would be easy to do a concat or something like that. Unfortunately, this is how the dataset comes and there isn't a way to know ahead of time which nickname will be used for which account (without spending just as much processing power at runtime).

The easiest way I could think of to solve this is with nested for/itterrow loops and if statements like the example below. If anyone knows of a faster way, that would be great since this method is excruciatingly slow to the point of being unusable for thousand-line dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names' : ['tim;timothy','tim', 'joseph', 'joe;joseph', 'bill', 'tim', 'bill', 'joe'],
                 'account' : ['w213', 'o993','x332', 'y313', 'z641', 'r323', 'p881', 'k445']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'names' : ['jill', 'joseph', 'tim', 'bill', 'timothy', 'bill', 'phil'],
                 'account' : ['y554', 'x332', 'w213', 'z641', 'w213', 'p881','k913']})


df1['new account'] = 1

for index_1, row_1 in df1.iterrows():
    possible_names = row_1['names'].split(';')

    for index_2, row_2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row_2['names'] in possible_names and row_1['account'] == row_2['account']:
            df1.loc[index_1, 'new account'] = 0

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

[image: df1][image: df2]

Comment: [Minor: please paste text, not images; the minor improvement in appearance isn't worth the practical loss of being able to copy and paste.]

Comment: @root: not only did I see them, I used those definitions to create my answer.  But the use of being able to copy and paste output remains, esp. when (as happened here) the samples changed.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the prettiest, but one way would be to expand and flatten your df1 and then do a merge with df2:

```
# flatten
df1_v2 = df1[["account"]].join(df1.names.str.split(";", expand=True))
df1_v2 = pd.melt(df1_v2.reset_index(),
                 ["index", "account"], value_name="names").dropna()

# merge
common = df1_v2.merge(df2)
df1["new account"] = 1
df1.loc[common["index"].values, "new account"] = 0
```

which gives me

```
  account        names  new account
0    w213  tim;timothy            0
1    o993          tim            1
2    x332       joseph            0
3    y313   joe;joseph            1
4    z641         bill            0
5    r323          tim            1
6    p881         bill            0
7    k445          joe            1
```

---

This goes via the intermediate

```
In [145]: df1_v2.head()
Out[145]: 
   index account variable   names
0      0    w213        0     tim
1      1    o993        0     tim
2      2    x332        0  joseph
3      3    y313        0     joe
4      4    z641        0    bill
```

Comment: This is great!!! It provides the same output and offers orders of magnitude speedups. The runtime for my large files went from hours to less than a second.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I thought you might appreciate the approach.

Answer (score 3):

## New Answer

***all together***

```
d1 = df1.set_index('account').names.str.split(';').apply(set)
d2 = df2.groupby('account').names.apply(set).reindex(d1.index, fill_value=set())

new = (d1 - (d1 - d2)).astype(bool).__neg__().astype(np.uint8).rename('new')
df1.join(new, on='account')
```

***explanation***
***use `set` operations***

```
# define series as `d1` and `d2` based on `df1` and `df2`
d1 = df1.set_index('account').names.str.split(';').apply(set)
d2 = df2.groupby('account').names.apply(set).reindex(d1.index, fill_value=set())
```

---

```
d1

account
w213    {timothy, tim}
o993             {tim}
x332          {joseph}
y313     {joseph, joe}
z641            {bill}
r323             {tim}
p881            {bill}
k445             {joe}
Name: names, dtype: object
```

---

```
d2

account
w213    {timothy, tim}
o993                {}
x332          {joseph}
y313                {}
z641            {bill}
r323                {}
p881            {bill}
k445                {}
Name: names, dtype: object
```

The `-` operator takes the set difference.  By doing this twice, if there is no intersection, I get an empty set.  empty sets evaluate to `False`.  But no intersection means a new account, so I take the `__neg__` (negation, aka `~`) to switch `False` to `True`.

```
# find where there is no intersection
new = (d1 - (d1 - d2)).astype(bool).__neg__().astype(np.uint8).rename('new')
# join
df1.join(new, on='account')

  account        names  new
0    w213  tim;timothy    0
1    o993          tim    1
2    x332       joseph    0
3    y313   joe;joseph    1
4    z641         bill    0
5    r323          tim    1
6    p881         bill    0
7    k445          joe    1
```

## Old Answer

@DSM's answer is much better
This is more of a stream of thought that landed on a solution

```
d2 = df2.assign(dummy=1).set_index(['account', 'names'])
split_df = df1.names.str.split(';', expand=True).rename(columns='name{}'.format)
d1 = df1.drop('names', 1).join(split_df)
d1 = d1.set_index('account').stack() \
       .reset_index('account', name='names') \
       .set_index(['account', 'names'])
df1.join(
    (~d1.join(d2).dummy.unstack().any(1)).astype(int).rename('new'),
    on='account')

  account        names  new
0    w213  tim;timothy    0
1    o993          tim    1
2    x332       joseph    0
3    y313   joe;joseph    1
4    z641         bill    0
5    r323          tim    1
6    p881         bill    0
7    k445          joe    1
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743773/python3-convert-csv-to-json-using-pandas